# Java version for Spring 3.1.1

Tags: spring

What version of Java do you need to be able to use Spring 3.1.1. The geeks of Spring never put down in their documentation clearly what version is needed. Someone please help.

Answer (score 5):

"
Java SE and Java EE Support

The Spring Framework is now based on Java 5, and Java 6 is fully supported.

Furthermore, Spring is compatible with J2EE 1.4 and Java EE 5, while at the same time introducing some early support for Java EE 6.
"

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.0.html#new-in-3.0-intro