# spring framework jdk compatibility

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, compatibility

We are planning to develop Spring Application. In our servers JDK version is 1.5(it cannot be changes as there are so many other applications running on the same server). I am planning to use Spring core , MVC modules.SO can any one suggest which version of spring is suitable for JDK 1.5.And also suggest which version of Hibernate is suitable for the selected spring version.

Thanks in Advance,

Rajesh

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346408/java-version-for-spring-3-1-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Spring 4 and Hibernate 4 require Java 1.6 so for Java 1.5 you should use:

- Spring 3.2.12.
- Hibernate 3.6.10

Comment: Thanks for your response Vlad Mihalcea

Comment: is spring 5 compatible with jdk 1.6